# Find the 'Best' element from the given list

Tags: puzzle

I was recently asked this question in one of my telephonic interview.

*"There is a list of elements. And you have to find the "**best**" element from the list. The elements are comparable to each other, but **the comparison is not transitive**. 
E.g. if A > B and B > C, then A need NOT be greater than C.*

*You have to return the best element as answer, which is better than every other element in the list. It is possible, that there is no such element. In that case, return null."*

**My solution:**

**Attempt 1:**

A simple **O(n^2)** solution. Comparison of each element with each other element.

The interviewer was not satisfied.

**Attempt 2:**

Start comparing first element with 2nd element and onward. For whichever element 'E', if A > E, mark E (may be by using another array/list/etc.) and do not consider E for any further comparison. This is because there is at least 1 element which is better than E, so E is definitely not the answer.

Complexity is still **O(n^2)** with some improvement as compared to previous attempt.

He was still not satisfied. Can anyone come up with any better solution?

Comment: I thought a max-heap might be a solution, but since the comparison is not transitive, it won't hold good ??

Comment: @brainydexter: yes, since comparison is not transitive, data structures like heap won't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure. You have N elements. Compare the first two. One of these is 'worse' than the other. Discard it. Compare the 'better' of the two with the next element. Continue this first pass across the list until only one element remains. This step is O(N).

The one element that survived the first pass now needs to be compared with every element from the original list except those that it was already compared with. If it 'loses' even once, you return that there is no 'best' element. If it 'wins' every comparison in this step you return this element. This step is also O(N).

This algorithm is O(N+N) = O(N) in the worst case and O(N+0) == O(N) in the best case. We can further prove that this is the best possible complexity because checking a solution is also O(N), and it cannot be less complex to get a solution than it is to check it.

Comment: This sounds convincing.  But isn't the result of the first pass merely some element that is greater than at least one other element?  i.e. there is nothing unique about the element returned.

Comment: Correct, however it is the only element that has *not* been confirmed to be *worse* than one other element. It may be worse than every other element except for one, which is why the second pass is necessary. The first pass is a simple way to narrow it down to one candidate.

Comment: fantastic!! i had to actually read your answer twice to make out the necessity of second pass! at first it sounds really convincing that the second pass is unnecessary..

Comment: You could save the position in the list at which a new "candidate" element was last selected, and only rescan up to that point in the second pass: other trailing elements have already been compared to the candidate....

Comment: Nice answer, this is very similar to the approach used to solve the Celebrity Problem. `Given N people, there can be at most 1 celebrity. Everyone will know the celebrity (if there is one). The celebrity knows no one. Find if a celebrity exists. The only helper function provided to you is a 'boolean knows(person1, person2)' returning true if person1 knows person2, false otherwise`.